# Using emacs for coloring display of texts

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a log file that has a lot of tagging information, i.e, "ERROR", "WARNING", "***". I want to show the log info with different color/fonts based on the tagging info.
How can I do that?

Do I have to come up with my own major/minor modes? Is there some elisp code that I can reuse?

Comment: <http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighLight>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this interactively with:

```
M-s h r regexp <RET> FACE <RET>
```

or

```
C-x w h regexp <RET> FACE <RET>
```

see the documentation for [Interactive Highlighting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html).  *Note:* The second key binding is only available after you've turned on Hi-Lock mode via <kbd>M-x global-hi-lock-mode</kbd>.

If you want to set up a minor mode to do this on a regular basis, I'd check out [`fixme-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FixmeMode) and modify things from there.

It might be useful to read the [Faces](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Faces.html#Faces) portion of the manual to understand what is going on.

Comment: C-x w h is not bound to any command in my standard Emacs (23.1.2). Instead, highlight-regexp is bound to M-s h r. Strange.

Comment: @mmmasterluke Thanks, I didn't notice that, I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

[Generic Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode) was designed to ease the creation of simple custom modes for things like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a similar function in hooks for modes you care:

```
(defun add-watchwords ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil '(("\\<\\(FIX\\|TODO\\|FIXME\\|HACK\\|REFACTOR\\):"
          1 font-lock-warning-face t))))
```

I use this for coding modes obviously, so you should adjust the items you want highlighted.